# Unpermitted parameters for has_many :through nested form in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I am trying to implement a has_many :through nested form in my Rails 5 app to create a project with users assigned to it. However, when I try to create the project, I face the following validation errors:

```
- Project users user company must exist
- Project users user email can't be blank
- Project users user email is invalid
- Project users user password can't be blank
- Project users user firstname can't be blank
- Project users user lastname can't be blank
```

These are validations I did for the user model but I do not understand why they appear when I create a project with nested users. In addition, the console indicated :fullname as an unpermitted parameters, as shown below.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3RtrzKKVrSOiGLYnHwubF3GaRAbcQE/61doRM5clT8GpFYeJoEVnU2lEmQsNwVO8qecdqig8xjwbTqqaqL1gYQ==", "project"=>{"name"=>"dsada", "description"=>"dadasd", "project_users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"user_attributes"=>{"fullname"=>["", "5", "4", "3"]}}},"choice"=>"1", "button"=>"", "company_id"=>"1"}
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: fullname
```

Could anyone enlighten me on why I am facing these validation errors and why fullname is considered unpermitted although i included them in project strong params? My codes are as shown below. Thank you!

```
#Model - project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users, inverse_of: :project
  has_many :users, through: :project_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_users
end

#Model - project_user.rb
class ProjectUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :project_users
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :project_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

#Model - user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_users, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :projects, through: :project_users
end

#Controller - projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @project = @company.projects.build
    @project.project_users.build.build_user
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @project = @company.projects.build(proj_params)
    if @project.valid?
      @project.save
      render 'show'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def proj_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, project_users_attributes: [:id, user_attributes:[:fullname]])
    end
  end
end

#Views - new.html.erb

<%= form_for [@company, @project] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.fields_for :project_users do |project_user_form| %>
    <%= project_user_form.fields_for :user do |user| %>
      <%= user.label :team_members %>
      <%= user.select :fullname, company.users.collect { |p| [ p.fullname, p.id ] }, {:prompt => 'Select Team Members'}, { :multiple => true} %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit => "" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is why your strong parameters does not work well.
You're saying in `proj_params` that `:fullname` is a field. But it's not just a field - it's an array of values. So if you change that to `:fullname => []` that'll permit the parameter.

But.. that doesn't make any sense.
Your code is trying to **create new users**, **not assign** them. That's why you get validations errors. The simplest way to prevent that is to pass IDs of user, which will try to update / build association, not *create*.
Then, you'd be better off to pass users' IDs from the view. Try passing `user_ids` instead of fullnames and don't forget `user_ids => []` in strong parameters.

Comment: hey @vladimir, thank you! do I do it like this?

params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, project_users_attributes: [:id, user_attributes:[:fullname]])
**to**
params.require(:project).permit(:name, :description, project_users_attributes: [:id, user_attributes:[:user_ids=>[ ]]])

Comment: @KengHong yes, like that.

Comment: thanks for your help! however i get the following error when i adopt your suggestion:-
**undefined local variable or method `user_ids' for #<ProjectsController:0x007fa90f685320> Did you mean? user_session**.
is there something i missed out on?